# Some questions related to the asymptotic properties of lasso

Tags: regression, prediction, inference, lasso, consistency

A couple of questions have been bothering me. Let's assume, the number of variables is fixed and only n can grow (I only focus on low dimensional datasets):

1. Is the lasso always is root n consistent estimator (asymptotically)? 
   In some papers, I have seen that:

   If $λ_{n}$/$\sqrt{n}$ → $λ_{0}$ ≥ 0, then $\sqrt{n}$($\beta^*$- $\beta$) $\rightarrow$ argmin(V(u))

   where V(u) is the asymptotic distribution of the lasso estimator (I think). Then we say the lasso is root n consistent. Isn't this always true?
   $λ_{n}$ is quite small compared to $\sqrt{n}$ in every lasso fit?
2. If the lasso is root n consistent, then lim $sup_{n}$ P($A_{n}$ - $A$) $\leq$ c $<$1

   where c is a constant depending on the true model, $A_{n}$ is the subset selected by lasso, and $A$ is the true subset of variables.

   is that mean it can not select the optimum subset of variables when lasso is root n consistent? thus it is not an oracle procedure?

Thanks a lot for your help, any comments are welcome.

reference:
Zou (2006)The Adaptive Lasso and Its Oracle Properties

Comment: The question is under-specified. To talk about root-n consistency you have to be talking about an infinite *sequence* of lassos as n increases, but you haven't given any details about how this sequence is behaving. For example, what's $\lambda$ doing as $n$ is changing? Is it constant? decreasing? something else? ... You also have to be careful about how you set things up in terms of the design -- since you have more observations as $n$ increases, what's going on with the $x$'s? You'd need to extend the $x$'s in very particular ways for this to make much sense

Comment: You also appear to be asking several different questions that I think should be asked separately. In particular the third question should be asked on its own -- and as it stands it's not a good question (adding 'adaptive' to something comes with *some* cost, so what is better depends on what you're trying to do better *at*); perhaps it would be better to ask about what the tradeoffs are.

Comment: In fact I see you have asked the third question prior to posting this. *Don't* post multiple versions of the same question -- so given you already posted the third question, remove it from this one.

Comment: And you've already asked about consistency [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/309050/consistency-of-lasso-linear-regression). I suggest you edit that question to incorporate what you seem to be asking here, but be sure to take account of the need to make it clear what the sequence of lasso regressions is as n goes to infinity as discussed above, particularly in relation to how the design ($x$'s) and $\lambda$ behave with increasing $n$.